# The conversion of the varchar value '5566778891' overflowed an int column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using SQL Server database and there's a column named Cell(VARCHAR) data type. While reading using `reader.Read()` I get the Conversion error. Can anyone kindly explain the reason for the error?

This is my code:

```
string myConnection = dbController.connectionString;
        string query1 = "SELECT ID, Name from Manager Where Cell = " + managerNo.Text;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                managerID = reader.GetString(0);
                mgrID.Text = managerID;
                managerNames.Text = reader.GetString(1);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I am reading the value from a textbox (managerNo). I have tested the query on SQL Server Management Studio as well:

```
select Name, DOB
from Contact
where Cell = 1233453411
```

When I use `Cell = 1233453411` without the value as string I get the conversion error, however using `Cell = '1233453411'` as a string the result is fetched.

Whats the reason for this and how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the data type of Manager.Cell?

Comment: @DourHighArch its varchar(max)

Comment: Your query needs to add quotes around `managerNo.Text` - just as you did when you ran the query manually. However, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection, which you should investigate.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a comparison between two different types, a string and an integer:

```
where Cell = 1233453411
```

SQL Server has to decide which type to use.  It decides on the more restrictive type, which is the number.  So, the string gets converted to a number.

Say, you have a cell phone in New York with a number like: 917-555-5555.  Well, that becomes a number like 9,175,555,555 and this exceeds the value of the maximum integer.  Hence, you would get a conversion overflow.

The moral:  Always use similar types when making comparisons.

EDIT:

What should you do?  Don't store telephone numbers as *numbers*; they should be stored as strings (for instance, leading zeroes can be important).

If could do a quick-and-dirty and put single quotes around the value of the parameter.  But, what you should *really* do is change your SQL code to use a parameter with a string type.  It is bad programming to just stuff values (particularly user input) into a query string.

Comment: So I should change the data type to int or bigint, right?

Comment: @EL323 . . . No, change the type to a string, because that is how the column is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in **SQL Server 2008 R2**. (Below is tested code)

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string str = "Server=.\\SQL2008R2;Database=Practice;User ID=sa;Password=123;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=0";

        string query1 = "SELECT * from tblTest Where Cell = " + textBox1.Text;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(str))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                string aa = reader.GetString(0);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Otherwise using can change you query like in below format.

```
string query1 = "SELECT * from tblTest Where Cell = '" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
```

Thanks